# 'Coupon with the same code already exists" error in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules, coupon-codes

i have created a shopping cart price rule with a coupon code "xxx". Then i deleted the coupon code from admin side. The again i created the shopping cart price rule with the same coupon id then the error "Coupon with the same code already exists." comes.

When i check the database table the entry is deleted from the **salesrule_coupon** table but the entry of the coupon code is not deleted from the **salesrule_coupon**, this causes the above error.

Why this happening ? i use magento 1.9.2.0

Answer (score 1):

First  deleted the Shopping Cart Price Rules And then created new rule with same coupon code. you can also check entry in table salesrule_coupon. or edit that Shopping Cart Price Rules and change dates, status etc. also you should clear cache and/or session of your magento.

Comment: Yes, this is a solution. But magento's default functionality is to remove the entry from salesrule_coupon table when the corresponding rule is deleted from the admin side. Currently this is not working anymore.